# 'Some index files failed to download' while updating

Tags: software-center, 12.10, sudo, software-sources

When running `sudo apt-get update` I get these following errors:

```
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
This is the command I used after installing Ubuntu from window installer.
I am sure my laptop is connected to internet. What can I do now?

Comment: I removed http:// before all links.. So, they can't be seen as links

Comment: I didn't upated it..  It's a fresh install using a ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso file

Comment: I changed the software source to other near by servers and run the command again,still the same problem is repeating, with the exception archieve.ubuntu.com is replaced with  http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in

Comment: I have an ubuntu server 12.04.1 as the master dns server including dhcpd. in my options file I had only the secondairy dns-server's ip in the allow query list, **when I added 127.0.0.1 the same problem was fixed.** Though, in the presented detection method (previous answer) I could not ping archive.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open synaptic manager, install/reinstall `ubuntu-extras-keyring` and then (in terminal) type `sudo apt-get update`.

cheers u'd get out from this error.

Comment: This did not work for me. Why would it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-extras-keyring` did not resolve this issue for me.

Answer (score 22):

As [vasa1 pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244238/cannot-connect-to-ubuntuarchive-hnsdc-com-how-to-install-g#comment302982_244238), the server your system is configured to use to download packages for installation **is [currently down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com)**.

## What to do when your download mirror is down...

The solution to this problem is to use change it to a different mirror (i.e., a different server).

### Option 1: Using Graphical Configuration Utilities

#### Open Software Sources

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksu software-properties-gtk`, and enter your password. (Alternatively, select *Settings...* at the lower left corner of the Update Manager, or go to Settings > Repositories in Synaptic).

- That's for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, which you are running. In later releases, you can just run `software-properties-gtk` and when you make changes, PolicyKit will authenticate you.
- Most people using newer releases have the Software Center and not Synaptic. In the Software Center, you would go to *Edit* > *Software Sources...*.
- The Update Manager is unchanged, but in new releases is called the Software Updater.

#### Change the Download Server

In the *Ubuntu Software* tab of the Software Sources window, there is a drop-down menu labeled *Download from*. Select your regional server. For example, I'm in the United States and it looks like this on my 11.10 machine:

[image: Software Sources window showing Server for United States being selected in the drop-down menu.]
<sup>**Software Sources window showing *Sever for United States* being selected in the "Download from" drop-down menu.**</sup>

You may see other servers listed in that short list (like the server you currently have set up).

You can use the *Main server* too but it is almost always considerably slower than using your regional server. (At least in the United States, anyway.)

If you want to use another mirror, you can look through a list of mirrors by clicking *Other...*.

[image: Choose a Download Server dialog in Software Sources, for picking an alternative mirror]

### Option 2: Manually Editing a Configuration File

#### Back Up and Open `sources.list`

Back up your `sources.list` file and open it in a text editor:

```
cd /etc/apt
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.old
gksu gedit sources.list
```

- If you've already ran the second line, don't do it again, unless you want to *overwrite* the old backup with a copy of the new configuration.
- For a text-based editor (not requiring any GUI), replace the third line with `sudo nano -w sources.list` (or `sudo vi sources.list`, or `sudo -e sources.list`).

In the text editor, replace every instance of your old server name with the new server name. For example, you could replace every instance of `ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com` with `us.archive.ubuntu.com`. (Your text editor, whichever you use, will facilitate this--you don't have to manually find each instance and type in the name of the new mirror.)

Save the file, quit the text editor, run `sudo apt-get update`, and it should work with the new server.

### Option 3: Command Line Substitution

[`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sed.1.html) allows you to write simple (or complicated) scripts that act on a file, one line at a time. So you can issue a single command that goes through `sources.list`, replacing all the instances of the old server name with the new server name.

First, go into `/etc/apt` and (unless you did so recently) back up the file:

```
cd /etc/apt
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.old
```

Then run `sed`:

```
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.tmp
sed 's/ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/' sources.list.tmp | sudo tee sources.list
sudo rm sources.list.tmp
```

- For an old server besides ***`ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com`***, change that as appropriate.
- For a new server besides ***`us.archive.ubuntu.com`***, change that as appropriate.
- I decided to copy `sources.list` into a temporary file and use that as `sed`'s input. This is one way to ensure that `sed` is not overwriting the file while it's still reading it.
- The `sed` "script" here is very simple. [This explains](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-0) how substitution works.

### But what download servers are there?

There are [over 400 registered Ubuntu mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) for installing and updating software.

These are called **archive mirrors**. This should not be confused with **CD mirrors**, where ISO images and related files for *installing Ubuntu* are stored.

Many servers provide both, and are thus both archive mirrors and CD mirrors. But many are just one of the two.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer also address "0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and **21 not upgraded**?" In other words, OP will want to do a dist-upgrade?

Comment: @vasa1 There's no reason to think that will still be the case once `sudo apt-get update` is successfully run. It's based on information about available packages that is out of date. Also, just saying "run `apt-get dist-upgrade`" wouldn't be a sufficient response to that, as sometimes `dist-upgrade` does not resolve dependencies in a good way--important packages might end up removed. (Probably not, but it's important to inspect what it proposes to do, rather than running ahead with it.) If this issue persists, I think it would likely be best asked as a separate question.

Comment: ThnQ .. It worked really well

Comment: Following **option 3**, I still get an error: `some index files failed to download`.

Comment: It should be noted that this could also happen if the repository no longer exists (permanently), when you update to a new version of Ubuntu, as well as many other reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Either the mirror is down or you internet connection has issues (can be temporary).

- make sure you can ping **google DNS** and **archive.ubuntu.com**:

  `ping -c3 archive.ubuntu.com`
  `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

  Both commands should return `0% packet loss` in the statistics line. Else your internet connection is down.
- If your connection seems fine then it is likely the mirror is down. Try choosing another one close to your location.

Comment: _PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.156) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms_

Comment: _PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms_

Comment: I am getting 100% packet loss instead of 0% loss..

Comment: Any suggestions??

Comment: you have to first take care of your internet connection. These links might help:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/connecting-wireless.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: Good suggestion. I had taken it for granted to check for my internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Go Terminal and follow below steps for solution...

```
sudo su (login as root)
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/
rm -fr *
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rm -fr *
cd /etc/apt
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.old
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.tmp
sed 's/ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/' sources.list.tmp | sudo tee sources.list
sudo rm sources.list.tmp*
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
sudo su # login as root
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/
rm -fr *
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rm -fr *
cd /etc/apt
cp sources.list sources.list.old
cp sources.list sources.list.tmp
sed 's/ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/' sources.list.tmp | tee sources.list
rm sources.list.tmp*
apt-get clean
apt update
```