# Why am I not able to update ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

Not able to update ubuntu even after cleaning with update and upgrade commands and henceforth not able to install softwares.
When I try I get the error

```
W: Failed to fetch ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/…  
   Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
```

Comment: You need to add more detail to this post, as it stands there is nothing on it that allows us to help you with. This is no question, its just a statement.

Comment: What happens when when you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` using a terminal? Can you edit your question with any errors or other issues that might come up?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Some index files failed to download' while updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating)

Answer (score 2):

I would try to change the ubuntu mirror from where you're trying to download updates.

Open **Software Sources** and in the **Ubuntu Software** tab change the **download from** server to another one.

then try updating again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:

Comment: @SandeepChava please in the future write additional info into the question (like I did just now for you :-))

Comment: this is the error message