# Cannot connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com, how to install g++?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, g++, compiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘Some index files failed to download’ while updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

I typed `sudo apt-get install g++` in the terminal and got the following output. I can't install `g++`, nor can I upgrade my system.

```
hrushi@hrushi-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
Suggested packages:
  g++-multilib g++-4.4-multilib gcc-4.4-doc libstdc++6-4.4-dbg libstdc++6-4.4-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++ g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,443kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.3MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libstdc++6-4.4-dev g++-4.4 g++
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
```

After this I always get `Failed to fetch information from ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com (120.88.46.4)`.