# "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Tags: apt

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed as a dual boot system with Windows 7.  Ubuntu loads normally, but when I try to update with Synaptic Package Manager, I get the following error message and the system stops there....

```
Failed to fetch http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease  
Failed to fetch http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/InRelease

(and other links listed too!)

Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is wrong please?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating

Your question is already asked here

Comment: I agree: I think [that answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/244257/22949) should solve this (or problems like it for others who find this question by searching).

Answer (score 2):

You should check your source file config : `/etc/apt/sources.list`

This website will also help you generate a sources.list : http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php

[image]

To better understand what can be the problem check your log files : `/var/log/dpkg.log` also `/var/log/apt`

Comment: Very many thanks for your help.  I edited the sources.list and this seems to have sorted the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This means that those mirrors are down for the moment (or permanently). You should replace them with good mirrors (ie. removing the `mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/` part will get you a good mirror) or replace them entirely with your own preferred mirror.