# update on ubuntu 14.04 "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Tags: updates, 14.04

I called `sudo apt-get update`, i got something like this

```
Err http: //ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
```

this

```
Err http: //ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages 
  404  Not Found
```

and this is what the last line look like

```
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

SO, anyone can help me?? FYI, this is from Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please check http://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating. If your question is not the same please come back to this one and mention why it is different. I hope http://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating will solve your problem (sometimes when I get this I just wait a bit and try again.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below line is not a valid PPA line, so delete it or put `#` symbol before it in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (you can edit it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`):

```
deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
```

And also remove the Not found PPA's:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:tiheum/equinox
```

Now run the `sudo apt-get update` command.