# Failure to upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my computer to Ubuntu 16.04; mine is 14.04.

Unfortunately, I couldn't upgrade it. I always have the error below whether I'm trying to upgrade it using update-manager or using the terminal.

The pictures below show the error.

[image]
Image #1

[image]
Image #2

Comment: check you network connection, ensure its working fine.

Comment: @AkshayPratapSingh It is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be you need to switch servers because the one your are downloading from is [down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating)

It could be some PPAs were not found. If so try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457780/update-on-ubuntu-14-04-e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-i)

Please note the entire error messages aren't visible on your screen snapshot.