# problem with installing apps and updating software sources

Tags: apt, 14.04, updates, software-center, update-manager

When I have try to install new software through terminal such as:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

I get the following error:

> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

When I try to use `--fix-missing` argument after `apt-get` it showed to me that could not fetch the sources.

When I use `sudo apt-get update` it cannot gather software sources and many of it ignored and have error.

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease 
Ign http://download.mendeley.com stable InRelease                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg     
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://download.mendeley.com stable Release.gpg
Connection failed [IP: 54.230.172.66 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Connection failed
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Ign http://download.mendeley.com stable Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://download.mendeley.com stable/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Connection failed
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://download.mendeley.com stable/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg      
Connection failed
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Connection failed
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
```

I have read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating) thread. I have removed `ubuntu-extras-keyring` but I could not install it again.

I think may be a problem with my internet connection but when I ping 4.2.2.4 it works correctly and I can browse the internet without any problem.

I cannot install any software or update software sources.

Comment: Does your DNS service work well? For example, can you ping security.ubuntu.com?

Comment: yes. I can ping security.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Download `ubuntu-extras-keyring` then install it. From:

   http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/ubuntu-extras-keyring/download
2. Then change download mirror (See `Download From:` drop list), using:

   ```
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```

   As mentioned in the answer with higher votes, ['Some index files failed to download' while updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating?lq=1)

Comment: thanks for your notes. I have download and install the ubuntu-extras-keyring but the problem does not solved. Also i have change the server to USA or main server but the problem still exist.

Comment: @mece1390, try open http://archive.canonical.com/dists/trusty/ in web browser then download `Release.gpg` file.

Comment: I have download it. what's next?

Comment: @mece1390, Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Yes, i use proxy server in my browser. But `$http_proxy` environment variable set to null.

Comment: @mece1390, Could you disable proxy for browser then retry http://archive.canonical.com/dists/trusty/ in web browser then download `Release.gpg` file. I think, the servers rejecting your IP (as it's from Iran)

Comment: Thanks. I check the link without any proxy. The link did not open.
When i change the my ISP everything work correctly. I think the restricted policies of my previous ISP reason of this problem.