# Cannot do update and cannot install any package

Tags: apt, ppa, official-repositories

I am a centos user but a friend asked me to install programs on his lubuntu 12.04.

For that I started to get an update but it did not work:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                                                                  
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease                                                                
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                                                                        
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg                                                                
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg                                                              
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                                                            
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release                                                                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                                                    
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release                                        
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources/DiffIndex                                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease                                               
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources/DiffIndex                                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                                                                       
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources/DiffIndex                               
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex                             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease                                         
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                      
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                               
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex                  
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg                                        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                                   
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex               
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release                                            
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex                              
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release                                                                 
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources                                                                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg                                                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages                                           
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex                         
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex            
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release              
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Sources                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                                   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-hu                                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-hu      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-hu      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-hu                
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-hu
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-hu
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-hu
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-hu
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-hu
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-hu
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My sources.list file contains the following:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.1)]/ quantal main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

There was some advice to remove ppa repositories but I could not find any in sources.list. And there is nothing in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

From the above, what is the problem here? 12.04 is long time support and have an end of life only in 2017 so that must not be. How can I do that update? Now I cannot install anything. The network works.

I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating) that tells the problem is with the mirror. But I checked and `hu.archive.ubuntu.com` does work.

Why am I getting these Ign messages then?

Comment: it's 12.10 not 12.04. 12.10 is no longer supported

Comment: you mean 12.04 is no longer supported, right? what can I do then?

Comment: 12.04 is supported but 12.10 is what your friend has installed. Quantal is 12.10

Comment: so I have to reinstall it?

Comment: it would be easier to fresh install 12.04 or the latest LTS 14.04  yes.

Comment: For your info also, Lubuntu LTS has 3 years support not 5