# exspected new version alert did not appear on release date

Tags: repository, release-management, mate

I have run 15.04 from beta one +2.  Now that the release date  of 23rd April has come and gone, I tried  `sudo apt-get update`  and `upgrade`.  I suspect the Vivid repositories in update manager need to be updated but I am fearful of deleting them as I am very fond of the mate environment//desktop.  Please advise

After I tried

```
sudo apt-get update && time sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I received the error message

> Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Comment: Sounds like your mirror could need updating. This is a possible duplicate of [some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating). Similar root causes might be described in the answer for [404 errors](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists). Once apt-get is provided good places to download from it will do it's job well.