# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server in Virtualbox - problems with apt-get update and Prosody

Tags: 12.04, apt, virtualbox, dependencies

Playing around with learning how to run an Ubuntu server (specifically, trying to set up Prosody as per a video on ArsTechnica, and a Linode guide), using Virtualbox. I've got it up and running, everything seems to be OK, until I try to update. Then I get several "failed to fetch" warnings because of hash sums? (Would post terminal output but I can't post links with <10 reputation!)

The "failed to fetch" bits seem bad, is this bad?

Also, following along with the linode guide, adding the prosody key works fine, but the same things happen upon trying to update again.  Apt-get upgrade seemingly works fine and doesn't throw up any warnings or errors.

Next, upon trying to install Prosody itself, I get yet another problem:

---

```
root@Tserver:~# apt-get install prosody liblua5.1-sec0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 prosody : Depends: lua-expat but it is not installable or
                    liblua5.1-expat0 but it is not installable
           Depends: lua-filesystem but it is not installable or
                    liblua5.1-filesystem0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
*****
```

I'm seemingly unable to install any of the dependencies on their own, either.

I'm self-admittedly a total noob when it comes to these things - am I missing something here?

Comment: What did you do following this guides?. Looks like you add some bad ppas to me.

Comment: The update problems start before adding a single thing. I start VirtualBox, create a new VM, install 12.04 from the .iso, using the virtual machine option in modes. I created a snapshot before trying to install Prosody, just a clean 12.04 server install. The update problems still exist with the clean install.

Comment: I tried a fresh install on the VM, and instead of doing the Virtual Machine mode at install, just did a full install, and am getting the same problem with the Failed to fetch warnings. Completely clean install, no other packages, etc, installed, did apt-get upgrade before anything else.

Comment: Is your internet connection working?. Have your tried to change your download mirror (check the 11 upvotes answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating/244257#244257)?

Comment: I believe the internet is working. I can SSH to the Ubuntu Server guest from both the host machine and my phone on the network, and can ping google.com and get results.

Comment: Then try to change the mirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading the server to 14.04LTS. Don't know why 12.04LTS was having that issue, but everything is up and running now.