# How can I fix this apt-get update error?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.
I was not able to update so I followed the instructions from [this Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating) answer.
Now I'm getting these error messages when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list sud/etc/apt/sources.list 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: where is the error message?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You seem to have made it into an `HTML` document somehow.

Comment: Also, it is `/etc/apt/sources.list ` not `sud/etc/apt/sources.list ` the `sud` part should not be there?

Comment: @blade19899 that "sud" probably should have been either "sudo" or "sed" and got included into the command used.  Either way ... that file is messed up probably.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your sources file is corrupted. Remove the corrupted source file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, and type in

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in `sudo software-properties-gtk`.
This will open software-properties-gtk and a new `sources.list` will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must
enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)