# signature verification error for wine - index files failed to download - changing mirror doesn't help

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, software-sources, gnupg

When I `sudo apt-get update` I get the error shown below.

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. 
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified
 because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified
 because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So I go ahead and change my mirror as suggested by [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating). Then I restart the computer. And I still get the same error above when I `sudo apt-get update`.

Let's try and reinstall the keys.

```
$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key && sudo apt-key add Release.key
File ‘Release.key’ already there; not retrieving. OK
```

And I might as well `ping -c3 archive.ubuntu.com` and my packet loss is 0%. What else do I need to do?

Comment: It looks like the new update for wine is signed with a different key than the Release.key they are hosting...

Comment: Please use code formatting for command output (just like commands), not quote formatting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Note that after adding the new keyfile, it is better to use `apt update` rather than `apt-get update`, as it will prompt you to accept the changes.

So in full:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo apt-key add winehq.key && sudo apt update
```

Comment: I also added the repository `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'` and this solution worked. As mentioned you must use `sudo apt update` and not `sudo apt-get update`. `apt` forces you to explicitly accept, whereas `apt-get` does not and will yield an error. If you have other versions of Ubuntu your repository to add can be found here https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: I would consider adding `rm winehq.key` or saving the file to the `/temp` at the beginning. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 24):

As of 2018-12-19 08:07 there is a new `winehq.key` keyfile as mentioned [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

Download the new repository key and add it to the list of trusted keys:

```sh
cd /tmp
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt update
```

As mentioned by @jason-hunter in a comment, `apt update` will ask if you accept the changes in the repository, whereas `apt-get update` will show an error and fail.

Answer (score 10):

Inspecting https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/, there's a new file [`winehq.key`](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key). Try using that instead, as its fingerprint seems to match the error:

```
# curl -sL "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key" | gpg --dry-run --import --verbose
gpg: pub  rsa4096/818A435C5FCBF54A 2015-11-23  Sebastian Lackner (WineHQ packages) <sebastian@fds-team.de>
gpg: Total number processed: 1
# curl -sL "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key" | gpg --dry-run --import --verbose
gpg: pub  rsa3072/76F1A20FF987672F 2018-12-10  WineHQ packages <wine-devel@winehq.org>
gpg: key 76F1A20FF987672F: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 1
```

Answer (score 7):

This command worked for me:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && apt-key add winehq.key
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently was getting the same error too:

```
Err:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
```

As it turns out, the pubkey needed to be added to my host.  Adding the key is the last 8 digits of the key you see there `F987672F`.  So add that to the following to add the key to your host:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F987672F
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I use docker witch node, java, angular and electron this works:

```docker
FROM node:16.15.0

WORKDIR /work
COPY package.json .

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install zip unzip

# node_modules witch angular and electron
RUN npm install -g n @angular/cli electron electron-builder

# JAVA
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
RUN apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless 

# Wine (Wine32)
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
RUN apt-key add winehq.key
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main'
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-stable

EXPOSE 3002
```