# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F

Tags: apt, wine, gnupg

When I type `sudo apt update` I get this response:

```
Get:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [6,242 B]
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Err:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've try to use `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 76F1A20FF987672F` to fix it, but noting is fixed:

```
gpg:keyserver receive failed: No data
```

How can I fix this? I uninstalled wine last week; have I not fully uninstalled it?

Comment: Check the repository list by `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep winehq` for unnessesary wine repo entry and disable the winehq line by adding a `#` before it and then re-run sudo apt update And if you want to fix wine, you can follow this https://askubuntu.com/q/1103240/505225 or you have to fix your wine key by `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo apt-key add winehq.key && sudo apt update`

Comment: when i type 'sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list |  grep  winehq' he give me this respond 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'

Comment: type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and put a `#` before that **deb dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic main # deb-src dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic main** line, press `ctrl+x` and then `y` and then `sudo apt update`

Comment: ok done ,  now when i type sudo apt update , not have dl.winehq anymore , thanks a lot , have a nice day ^_^

Comment: you should also take a look at the similar problem https://askubuntu.com/q/1103240/505225 here :)

Comment: @SamLo I had the same error recently and the duplicated link here did not help.  What I had to do, and now the key is there, is to run the following:  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F987672F` and then it worked for the winehq site.