# sudo wget returns OpenSSL error when trying to install Wine, meanwhile wget does not work due to permission denied

Tags: wine, 22.04, wget, openssl

[Screenshot of what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYeYm.png)

```
(base) josaphat@josaphat-GS66-Stealth-10SGS:~$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
--2022-10-29 12:46:53--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
OpenSSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
OpenSSL: error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file
OpenSSL: error:05880002:x509 certificate routines::system lib
OpenSSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
OpenSSL: error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib
OpenSSL: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
(base) josaphat@josaphat-GS66-Stealth-10SGS:~$ wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
/etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key: Permission denied
```

Been trying to read similar issues online such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/979113/why-does-wget-give-an-error-when-executed-with-sudo-but-works-fine-without). However, `env | grep proxy` returns nothing for me.

Comment: @Terrance the problem is that now sudo wget returns the same OpenSSL error when i tried to sudo wget any links. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You could be having an issue in the conda environment.  See:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026383/why-does-base-appear-in-front-of-my-terminal-prompt  Another thing is, when did you first start seeing the OpenSSL error?

Comment: @Terrance I haven't been messing around with my conda environment for a while, it has stayed there for months. As for the first time seeing the OpenSSL error, it starts out to appear when I'm trying to manually register a public key to update my wine (I followed [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103320/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai) ). I might have edited some things on the apt-key list, but I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: I am going to take stabs in the dark, but maybe try reinstalling OpenSSL  `sudo apt install --reinstall openssl`