# Apt Update : NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F (wine)

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I am simply trying to run `sudo apt update`, but am encountering the seemingly classic error of:

```
Err:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Err:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
```

This is all well and good. Several sources [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103392/1001435)[[2]](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/updates/updates-failure-series-3-x-wine-no_pubkey-76f1a20ff987672f-error-fix/) Mention this as a quick and easy fix, specifically for that key:
`wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo apt-key add winehq.key && sudo apt update`

But when I run the command, but it still bounces back at the `sudo apt update` step with the same error, even though the key seemed to have been correctly added. I even double checked this like so:

```
$ apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
[...]

pub   rsa3072 2018-12-10 [SC]
      D43F 6401 4536 9C51 D786  DDEA 76F1 A20F F987 672F
uid           [ unknown] WineHQ packages <wine-devel@winehq.org>
[...]
```

The key has clearly already been added, and the later half of the string associated with the key listing also corresponds (`DDEA 76F1 A20F F987 672F` ~= `76F1A20FF987672F`).

What am I missing? Why does `sudo apt update` seemingly just ignore this newly added key?

How can I run `sudo apt update` successfully in this situation?

Comment: Everything is in the instructions: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu
For example: wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo mv winehq.key /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key
further wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources && sudo mv winehq-jammy.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: Ah, perfect, your solution worked

Comment: First bullet point in the "Winehq key problems" section fixes it for me. I'm always amazed how little the wine devs care for user experience :-P Especially as wine has a lot of users that just switched from Windows to Linux and have no idea how those things work ...

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem too. In my case, the solution was to simply follow the instructions at the WineHQ Wiki when **adding the repository**, see page [Ubuntu WineHQ Repository](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

```
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings

sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

It looks that the old variant to add the repo is no longer working. The new method must be used which works for me perfectly well. No longer any **: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F** error message! :-D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same trouble, I tried removing the repo files but adding the latest key resolved my error

```
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.

I tryed to solve using the **Program Update** interface, but it doesn't worked.

So I found this: (below the link for the complete article)

**1. Identify problematic repositories:**

> > sudo apt update

**2. Go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder and locate the unwanted repositories files**

> > cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && ls

**3. Manually remove unwanted files**

> > sudo rm problematic-repository-name-.list*

######### EXAMPLE #########

> > sudo rm ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list*

4. Try **sudo apt update** again. (if it works for you, repet the process for each unworking repository.)

Complete article [here](https://www.blogopcaolinux.com.br/2017/02/Como-remover-um-repositorio-PPA-no-Ubuntu.html).

PS.: It is in portuguese but is simple and functional. Credits and thanks to: [Sandro de Castro](https://www.blogger.com/profile/13322532100313253130))

**FOR THE NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F problem:**

1. Open the **Program Updat** -> **Setings** in the **Auth** or **Authentication**
2. Select the **76F1A20FF987672F** then click **Remove**
3. Close, done!

**If you prefer to try to fix the repository instead of removing it. Try this:**

[EXECUTION ERROR - WINE [SOLVED]](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Wine-Wine-X-Cedega/Erro-na-Execucao-Wine)

For more information you might want to see [this](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

> > Apt-key is now deprecated. If you get a warning about this, remove the key with:
> > sudo apt-key del "D43F 6401 4536 9C51 D786 DDEA 76F1 A20F F987 672F"
> > And remove the the line about the WineHQ repository from /etc/apt/sources.list.

I'm not a Linux expert, but I hope I could have helped you.

Best regards!
Rodrigo Souza

Comment: I don't understand. This all just seems to say, "If it doesn't work, delete it and stop trying." The link for "try[ing] to fix the repository instead of removing it" just listed the same instructions for adding the key, except in Spanish. They don't work, as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: For me, this turned out to be an apparent freak error in downloading the winehq-focal.sources file, where a slash was omitted from the key path. Adding back the slash fixed the problem.