# apt-get upgrade fails on KDE Neon 18.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, kde

I try to update my KDE Neon Linux Ubuntu 18.04 distribution to a newer one, preferably 22.04 but when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade` it tells me

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

And when I then run `sudo apt-get update` to update all packages it fails with the following output

```
Get:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [6'263 B]       
Err:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Couldn't find a specific solution for my problem, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt Update : NO\_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F (wine)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413071/apt-update-no-pubkey-76f1a20ff987672f-wine)

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missing wine's public key. Make sure you have a /usr/share/keyrings directory first.

Then try this:

```
sudo wget -nc -O /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```