# apt update fails. Says key not available

Tags: apt, updates, wine

I am attempting to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Running
`sudo apt update`  fails with message `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F`. The thing is this key **does** exist. `sudo apt-key list` returns

```
pub   rsa3072 2018-12-10 [SC]
      D43F 6401 4536 9C51 D786  DDEA 76F1 A20F F987 672F
uid           [ unknown] WineHQ packages <wine-devel@winehq.org>
```

I even tried deleting and recreating the key. Full output from `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                   
Get:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease [8,041 B]                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                           
Ign:6 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease                                                                                              
Ign:7 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:9 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release                                                                                                
Hit:10 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ Release                                                                                                      
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                               
Err:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Ign:14 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease                                                                                                       
Hit:15 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                                                                                              
Err:16 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release                                                                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.21.37.199 443]
Hit:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fontforge/fontforge/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                               
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                              
Hit:26 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 InRelease                                         
Hit:17 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                                                             
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
Hit:24 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease                        
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                       
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Related: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629) When you add a PPA or other source to your system, you're changing the composition of your system and its available software. This can cause problems with dependencies for other software, *especially* if you add sources that are outdated or incompatible. Several of your sources are outdated and/or incompatible. Depending on how long this condition has existed on your system, it may be more difficult to fix problems. Reinstalling a supported release may be the best path forward.

Comment: This question is aimed at: '...asking how to upgrade to a supported release.' So as long as it is *supported release*, which is not clear I admit, the question should be ok. The Original Poster will make life easier by specifying what is the targeted upgrade version of Ubuntu; although this is not the centre of the issue faced here...

Comment: wine-noob saying this: remove wine to allow upgrade, reinstall after upgrade. Note: software added after a "clean install" is likely to be a hindrance in upgrades.

Comment: Also, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103240/signature-verification-error-for-wine-index-files-failed-to-download-changin

Comment: see also [How to fix: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789307/how-to-fix-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing the pub key? You can try pulling Debian keys from the Ubuntu Keyserver like such:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 76F1A20FF987672F
```

Comment: Running apt update after pulling that key results in the same error message