# 'Failed to fetch' and 'Temporary failure resolving' errors on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, updates, 20.04

When I run `sudo apt update`, I get the following errors:

[image: screenshot of errors]

NOTE: This error only occurs when I am connected to my home wifi. When using another wifi it seems to work just fine (no errors at all).

What could be causing this? And are there any fixes?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you remove some of the repositories as they have been deprecated?
Re run updates

Comment: @AkshatZala how do I know which repository is deprecated?

Comment: @AkshatZala Alright I removed a bunch of repositories, and I am no longer getting the errors. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Some index files failed to download' while updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208037/some-index-files-failed-to-download-while-updating)